# lmer: repeated measures additive model, testing pairwise comparisons

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I have a longitudinal data set that contains a repeated measurement of the same participants over 6 different measurement times. I've built my model via lmer in r:

```
Model <- lmer(output ~ Fa + Yr + Yrs + Age + Hrs + (1|PartID) + (1|Scenario), 
               data = data)
```

where the participant id is crossed with the repeated scenario.

I was able to calculate the F-stats and their associated significant levels for an omnibus test, but I need to assess which scenarios the Iv's best predict via a pairwise comparison.

Is there a way to do this under the framework of a repeated measure in lmer?

Additionally, my data is non-parametric and required a permutation of the F-statistics. Is there a method of also permutating the pairwise comparison t-statistics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few packages that handle objects created by `{lme4}` commands in R:

- `{emmeans}`. `pairs()` function will do pairwise comparisons and give you test statistics. [See vignette at CRAN.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html#pairwise)
- `{ggpredict}` will do this, as well. [See Vignette at CRAN.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/vignettes/ggeffects.html) This package has a focus on returning objects that are ready for plotting.
- `{sjPlot}` also focuses on plotting, but will show you marginal effects, too. [See Vignette via the package's website.](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/articles/plot_marginal_effects.html)

I personally use `emmeans`, but mainly because that's the one I heard about first.